# What is publishable key in 2checkout?

Tags: 2checkout

In [2Checkout Python Tutorial](https://www.2checkout.com/documentation/libraries/python/tutorial), they say I need to replace sandbox-seller-id and sandbox-publishable-key with my own credentials. I have my SID, but where do I find this **publishable key**? I can't find it in my sandbox account.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The publishable key should be displayed on the [API settings](https://sandbox.2checkout.com/sandbox/api) page. It's on the right hand side of the page under "Key Generator". The key is valid for 1 hour after generation.